# Node.js/express.js default routing changes not being seen in ubuntu

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, express, routes

EDIT ------------

so I figured out the issue, restarting and reloading nginx didn't have any effect, but if I stoped the nginx instance, then restarted it, any changes I made to the server files took effect. It's great that I figured it out, but could anyone give me some insight into why this is? It's better if I understand why this was happening. Any changes I made to the client side files such as the html files took affect immediately, it was only the server files that I had to stop then restart the nginx instance for it to take affect.

ORIGINAL POST BELOW----------------------

Any changes I make to the server side files of my deployed Node.js app with express.js isn't being seen by ubuntu. Basically, I have a mean app deployed on ubunut, it is a multipage page app, with only one of those pages having partials, so i use my routes.js 
to catch the routes and send them to my main.js file to tell express and node which html or ejs file to load.

I made changes to the version on my computer so that all other routes would go to a certain html, it works great. But I pushed my changes to github, then pulled them in my ubuntu instance, and it's not working. All other changes I made to the project during this time that were pushed with it have taken affect. But, it's like ubuntu isn't letting node see any changes to the routes.js file, the code is there, I've even altered it with 'vim' from my terminal, but any changes I make, even ones that should break it, aren't seen by node. And going to an unexpected route displays the 'cannot GET...' page.

I've wracked my brain, but i'm stumped, the code is there and I can change it, I've altered html pages via vim to test it. But both, the routes.js file that handles my routing and my server.js file aren't reflecting my changes, even when I change things that should break it. Any ideas? Let me know if you need anymore info, i've included my files below. Also, I use nodemon so that it restarts automatically anytime changes are made

SERVER.JS FILE -------------------------------

```js
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    path = require('path'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './client')))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './client/views')))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './bower_components')))
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, './client'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


require('./server/config/routes.js')(app)

var port = 8000
app.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('Server on port: ' + port)
})
```

ROUTES.JS FILE -----------------------------

```js
var Main = require('../serverControllers/main.js')

module.exports = function(app){
  app.get('/', Main.main)
  app.get('/contact', Main.contact)
  app.get('/algorithms', Main.algorithms)
  app.get('/projects', Main.projects)
  app.get('*', Main.other)
  app.use(Main.other)
}
```

MAIN.JS FILE ----------------------

```js
module.exports = {
  main: function(req, res){
    res.render('index')
  },
  contact: function(req, res){
    res.render('contact')
  },
  algorithms: function(req, res){
    res.render('algorithms')
  },
  projects: function(req, res){
    res.render('projects')
  },
  other: function(req, res){
    res.render('default')
  },


}
```

Comment: You've restarted the Node process right?

Comment: I'm using nodemon so it automatically restarts anytime changes are made, is that what you mean?

Comment: That's likely your issue. Nodemon is also not meant for production, so I suggest you instead write a systemd service (if you have Ubuntu 15.04 or greater) or upstart service to handle starting and restarting. They also automatically start your application when your server boots.

Comment: You know what, that was my mistake, I use nodemon on my computer, but on ubuntu I use nginx, but I still can't see how that is the problem, I don't have to restart/reload nginx after I pull from github, and I didn't have to do it for the changes I made to the html to take effect. And I did restart nginx to see if that was the problem, still didn't take care of the problem.